# How do I hit a modified /etc/hosts from VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, hosts

I have an app that I have to change the `/etc/hosts` file to be able to hit.  Here is my new file.

```
#127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.0.1       local.connectwithme
```

This works easily on my local machine.  I just go to `local.connectwithme:3000` in my browser and I am able to view my app.

I am now trying to view it with `VirtualBox` running `Windows 7`.  Typically I would just go to the ip address `10.0.2.2` in the browser of the virtual machine and access the `localhost` of my host machine from the `VirtualBox`, but now that I have changed the `/etc/hosts` file on my host machine I don't know what I need to hit to see my app on the virtual machine.  Could someone please explain this to me.  Thanks.

Comment: By "hit", I think you mean access, right? In this problem, you have a server running on port 3000 on your host OS, and want to access the server from within the Windows guest OS, correct?

Comment: This depends on what kind of networking you have configured VirtualBox with. Are you using NAT, Bridged, or something else? You can find your network configuration in the settings dialog for your Virtual Machine in the Network setting.

Comment: Is the problem that accessing `10.0.2.2:3000` no longer works through the VM guest, or you want to access the host OS using the name `local.connectwithme:3000` from the guest?

Comment: I am trying to access `local.connectwithme:3000` from the guest and it doesn't map to anything.  I just get a address not known error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To access the host OS when using a NATed Virtual Box connection, you need to determine the IP address of the host OS (on the other side of the NAT) and then add this IP address to the hosts file on your guest OS:

1. From within the guest OS, determine your default gateway. This will be the IP address of the host OS. The easiest way to do this is to open a command prompt and run `ipconfig /all`. Under the `Ethernet adapter`, find the Default Gateway. This is almost certinaly **10.0.2.2** if you haven't changed anything.
2. Now, find your hosts file and add the host IP address. On Windows 7, this file is located in `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\`.

   1. Start Notepad with administrator privileges (Start|Run, type "notepad", right click and choose "Run as administrator."
   2. Open up `%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` in Notepad (you'll need to change it to show all files).
   3. Add an entry to the hosts file mapping the host IP address to the hostname you want, such as: `10.0.2.2 local.connectwithme`